# How to initialize Kotlin IntArray from IntRange?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to initialize an `IntArray` in Kotlin like so:

```
intArrayOf(1..9)
```

But I get a `TypeError` that `Int` is required, but I'm providing an `IntRange`. Is there a way to initialize the array with a range, or do I have to explicitly write out each value?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using built in functions, this is how you could get to an `IntArray` from an `IntRange`:

```
val array: IntArray = (1..9).toList().toIntArray()
```

This is a bit wasteful, because it first constructs a list where it puts all the elements, and then it constructs an array as well. To do this directly, you could use your own extension, something like...

```
fun IntRange.toIntArray(): IntArray {
    if (last < first)
        return IntArray(0)

    val result = IntArray(last - first + 1)
    var index = 0
    for (element in this)
        result[index++] = element
    return result
}
```

Which would give you this syntax:

```
val array: IntArray = (1..9).toIntArray()
```